# change position on menu using div

Tags: html, css

First of all, I'm new to HTML and CSS so please be kind with me!:)

So, for a school assignment I need to replicate the IKEA website. I'm having a problem where a menu drops down about 150px

What it needs to be:

[image]

What I got:

[image]

The part in the blue box needs to go where the arrow points.

The code I got:

HTML:

```
    <header>
        <h1>
            <a href="index.html">
                <img src="logo.gif" alt="IKEA" title="Klik hier om terug te gaan naar de hoofdpagine" />
            </a>
        </h1>

        <div id="login">
            <p>Welkom bij IKEA België! <a href="#">Log in<a> of <a href="#">maak een profiel aan<a></p>
        </div>

        <div id="headerlinkswrapper">
            <div class = "headertaal">
                <a href="#">NL</a>
                <a href="#">FR</a>
            </div>

            <div class = "headerlijst1">    
                <a href="#">Winkel informatie</a>
                <a href="#">IKEA FAMILY</a>
                <a href="#">Mijn boodschappenlijs</a>
            </div>

            <div class = "headerlijst2">
                <a href="#">Startpagina</a>
                <a href="#">Mijn profiel</a>
                <a href="#">Jobs@IKEA</a>
            </div>

            <div class = "headeranna">  
                <a href="#">Vraag het aan Anna"</a>
                <a href="#">Vraag het aan Anna</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <nav id="hoofdmenu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Alle producten</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Nieuw</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Promoties</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Inspiratie</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Plannen</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Praktische info</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3D Keukenplanner</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Alle afdelingen</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    background-color: white;
    width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
}

#wrapper > header {
    height: 200px;
}

#wrapper > header {
  position: relative;
}

#wrapper > header h1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#login {
    position:relative;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#hoofdmenu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px auto;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    float: inherit;
}


#headerlinkswrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    margin-left:450px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there.

```
#headerlinkswrapper {
    margin-top: -140px; /* I'm estimating distance, change this! */
}
```